# Is it possible to get S3 files using ONLY modified date from server-side?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Most available solution are giving a **client-side** solution, which is not **performance-optimal.**

I am looking for a solution from the **server-side**, where I do not need to get files locally(client), and then to filter through them.

What I want to achieve is something like an AWS method, where I call something similar to this:

```
 var filesAfterCertainModifiedDate = s3.GetFilesAfterLastModifiedDate(modifiedDate);
```

And AWS makes the query filtration for me,

It's related to this issue:
https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1104

Is that possible?

Comment: No such feature exists in the [underlying S3 API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Operations_Amazon_Simple_Storage_Service.html).  At best, you can setup [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html) and parse the results, though you will still need to filter the results somehow.

Comment: Thanks Anon, It indeed seems like there is no solution from the server-side, I am not sure how can I put your comment as an answer, but thanks